# JSP error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, mariadb

thing used : eclipse, java 1.8.0 version, mariadb 10.2, mariadb-java-client-2.4.1jar

problematic point : I have only used **oracle db** until now, but it is my first time using **maria db**.

Integrated with db in **eclipse>Util.java**. However, when you create a jsp page and enter data(Data query results ("select * from..." sql statement with db)),

the **[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver]** error appears.
The **jdk version** I'm using is **1.8**, so I have to use **52.0**,

but I don't know what to Whether to use. I've **already used 2.x** among **jar versions**. But no. I'd appreciate it if you could help me solve it.

**my Util.java code**

```
package DBPKG;

import java.sql.*;

public class Util {
    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                            "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/board",
                            "root",
                            "1234");
        return conn;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Util.getConnection());

    }
}
```

**Console Results**

```
org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection@58fdd99
```

[image: add mariadb.jpa]

Comment: I don't know how you're running your Java programme but your MariaDB jar file `mariadb-java-client-2.4.1jar` must be included in your classpath.

Comment: Buhake Sinidi - As you said, you can find ```mariadb-java-client-2.4.1``` in ```C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.2\lib.```
We added this as ```java build path > addexternal jars```.

Comment: Are you running your application inside Eclipse? I assume that your application is bundled into a `war` file. If that's the case, then the driver JAR file must also be bundled in the `war`.

Comment: Yes, I think I added it. I put a picture in the body of the question. Just let it slide once. Thank you.

Comment: The Java Build Path page controls what you compile against. The Deployment Assembly property page controls what's included in your .war file. Is the jar also set up there?

Comment: I solved it. Thank you. ```Solution :  New Project > added jar to the Java Build Path > library```. I didn't know the build path page controls the compilation. Thank you very much.I always used Ojdbc, but I got lost trying to use Maria's jar.Thank you very much.

Comment: -Buhake Sindi, -nitind Thanks to you, can do what I want to do.